# Find and sort all of the extremum of $f(x,y) = |3x| + x^4y^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find and sort all of the extremum of $f(x,y) = |3x| + x^4y^2$

not quite sure what to do with the absolute value of $|3x|$ , should i separate it to two options? , one for $3x>0$ and the other option for $3x<0$ ?

Comment: from $f(x,y) = |3x| + x^4y^2= 3|x| + |x|^4|y|^2$ I think you can discuss with $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$ in $f(x,y) = 3x + x^4y^2$.

Comment: how do i differentiate it? $f_x = 3+4x^3y^2  $ ? am i supposed to just ignore the absolute value?

Comment: Its minimum value is $0$, all along the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from $f(x,y) = |3x| + x^4y^2= 3|x| + |x|^4|y|^2$ I think you can discuss with $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$ in $f(x,y) = 3x + x^4y^2$.

$f_x=3+4x^3y^2=0$

$f_y=2x^4y=0$

with the second $x=0$ or $y=0$ which both are impossible as conflict with the first, remains 
$$f(x,y) = |3x| + x^4y^2= 3|x| + |x|^4|y|^2\geq0=f(0,0)$$
specifies the only minimum point in the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it is clear that $$3|x|+x^4y^2\geq  0$$ so the Minimum is given by $$(0,0)$$